# Does ArcGIS Server allow the output data to be stored in a database?

Tags: spatial-database, database, wps

There is a chapter in my bachelor thesis on **database output storage support within various WPS implementations**. In other words, I want to find out if the output data (data derived from processes executed on a server) can be stored in a database (such as PostGIS).

For example, the ZOO-Project, one of the implementations of the WPS standard, includes such option and explains it on their website:

http://www.zoo-project.org/docs/install/installation.html#zoo-install-db-backend

Now, I need to cover geoprocessing services executed on ArcGIS Server in this chapter as well, but I cannot find the information I need on the Esri website.

So, if I am a consumer of a process executed on an ArcGIS Server, what options do I have as for storing the output data?

**Is there an option to store the data within a (spatial) database?**

Comment: This question assumes uniformity on the implementation of geoprocessing services that don't exist in the real world. It also genericises a number of different Esri solutions. Please [edit] the question to specify what you mean by "Esri Web Processing".

Comment: Could you please list the "different Esri solutions"?

Comment: ArcGIS Online, Portal/Enterprise, Server.  Your question is far too broad. Any of these **can** store data in a database, and frequently do. The specific protocols you call out have no bearing on the question, and therefore only confuse the issue.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "the specific protocols you call out have no bearing on the question". I suggested couple of possible answers to the previous question so it is easier to understand what I am looking for. I am not a native speaker and therefore my ability to express my thoughts is limited.

Comment: The specific protocols that you called out are "WMS, WFS, WCS" so I think you should delete that question from your question. Is your question purely about WPS from ArcGIS Server writing results to geodatabases, or something else?

Comment: An "Esri server" is a server owned by Esri. If you mean the product "ArcGIS Server", then use that instead. You're asking about services that store data in a database, but reference **output** WxS protocols and the shapfile format, which can't be a database table. Your title and final sentences ask different questions. I'd like to help, but it's unclear if you understand that ArcGIS Server can do ***anything*** that the C#, Java, and Python languages can do, which means that pretty much all "Is it possible" questions are going to result in a mostly useless "Yes."

Comment: Yes, my question is about WPS from ArcGIS Server writing results to databases, but, the way I understand it, a "geodatabase" is something different, that is a proprietary service by ESRI. I am interested in options for storing outputs in spatial databases such as PostGIS, SpatiaLite, Oracle Spatial etc.

Comment: Vince, I think now the title and final questions are asking the same thing. 

I will try to clarify the question one more time. If I publish a process on  ArcGIS Server for others to consume, do I get to choose what format the output data will be in? Or does the consumer of the process choose the format? Or neither of them?

Comment: No, a geodatabase is not a proprietary service. There are a near-infinite number of options for data storage, because ArcGIS supports a thousand different formats, but only if the service is engineered to support them. There is no answer for the generic case, because it is dependent on the ***publisher*** as to the capability of the service -- If the publisher *choses* to make options available, then the options are that which the publisher has chosen (and implemented).

Comment: If you set up a WPS service with ArcGIS server, then you get to decide what the requestable output formats are, and a user of the WPS service gets to choose which output format they want from those offered.  A user can't request a format that isn't supported by your service, even if in principle ArcGIS can support that output format.